# ASP.NET CORE: The target "ResolveRuntimePackAssets" does not exist in the project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have just created a new project in ASP.NET Core C# Web application. I am building the project, and it seems I have come across some strange error. I am not sure what does it mean.

The error says:

> The target "ResolveRuntimePackAssets" does not exist in the project

I manually tried adding `<Target Name="ResolveRuntimePackAssets" />` in Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**OTHER INFORMATION**

- .NET CORE Version: Version 3.1
- Visual Studio 2019

Thanks

Comment: Which operation will cause this issue? Can you tell us the details steps to reproduce the problem? You can start it from creating a new application, then tell us what you do will cause this problem.

Comment: I just created a new .NET CORE application. When I build it without adding any new page or making changes in it, it showed the error.